# How to return the highest spending customer in 2 quarters?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a data set (AdventureWorks db) with fields like 'totalDue, CustomerID, OrderDate, OrderNumber'. I have to show the top customer and total amount they spent over any 2 quarter period from the 3 years (07/01/2005 to 07/31/2008) available in the data. We were told that it can be a range of any period of 6 consecutive months, but for like every year. And perhaps the best way to do it is with "Over BY Partition function".

I have tried numerous ways, but I am not getting the correct amount spent.

[image]

```
select 
    top 1 CustomerID,
    dateadd(qq,2, OrderDate) qtr,
    Sum(TotalDue) sum_totaldue
From Sales.SalesOrderHeader
Group by
    CustomerID, 
    dateadd(qq, 2, OrderDate)
Order by sum_totaldue desc
```

So far, I have this query which is giving me the right CustomerID: 29641, but not the right total amount for 2 quarters. It is only giving me the highest amount order out of all the orders he made.

[image: Wrong Output]

The answer to the amount is : **$ 369,506.4522**, which is the sum of the last 2 quarters. But I am not being able to sum the total for those 2 quarters.

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server MS

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use analytic `SUM` function since you're already doing `GROUP BY`.

Try this:

```
select 
    top 1 CustomerID,
    datepart(q, OrderDate) qtr,
    Sum(TotalDue) sum_totaldue
From Sales.SalesOrderHeader
Group by
    CustomerID, 
    DATEPART(q, OrderDate)
Order by sum_totaldue desc
```

Comment: I tried it and it is giving me a different CustomerID. It is showing 29614 instead of 29641. Does the code above separate 2 quarters each year? We were told we need to find it for every 2 quarter period. This is confusing.

Comment: @Truecolor It doesn't yet. Can you post sample data (may be DDL/DMLs) and the expected output explaining how it calculated in the question?

Comment: I have edited the code in my post. So far, my query is giving me the right CustomerID: 29641, but not the right total amount for 2 quarters. It is only giving me the highest total spent in one date from all the purchases.